# i want to sorting my listview by user Android

Tags: android, listview

i have 2 classes to show some data in list view

but i want make option for users to sort this list view

this is adapter class

```
public class CustomListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
     private Activity activity;
        private Book[] data;
        private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
        public CustomListViewAdapter(Activity a, Book list[]) {
            activity = a;
            data=list;
            inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        }

        public int getBookId(int position){
            return data[position].getId();
         }

        public int getCount() {
            return data.length;
        }

        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View vi=convertView;
            if(convertView==null)
                vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);
            TextView row_id =(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.row_id);
            TextView name=(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.title);
            TextView descp = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.artist);
            TextView note_type = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.row_note_type);
            ImageView image=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.image);
            row_id.setText(String.valueOf(data[position].getId()));
            name.setText(data[position].getTitle());
            descp.setText(data[position].getContent());
            //row_id.setText(data[position].getId());
            note_type.setText(data[position].getType());
            //image.setImageResource(R.drawable.subway);
            if(data[position].getImage().toString().equals("Facebook")){
                image.setImageResource(R.drawable.facebook);
            }else if(data[position].getImage().toString().equals("skype")){
                image.setImageResource(R.drawable.skype);
            }else if(data[position].getImage().toString().equals("Subway")){
                image.setImageResource(R.drawable.subway);
            }else if(data[position].getImage().toString().equals("Book")){
                image.setImageResource(R.drawable.book);
            }
            return vi;
        }
}
```

and this is book class

```
public class Book {
    private int id;
    private String title;
    private String content;     // this is content of table
    private String image;       // choosing images
    private String type;        // type of table ( note or task)
    private int archived;       // Archive table (true or false) 
    private int check;          // make overline when finish (true or false)
    private int protect;        // protect the table with password (true or false)
    private String password;    // password of table if it was protected
    private String date_added;

    public Book() {}

    public Book(String title, String content, String image, String type, int archived, 
                int check, int protect, String password) {
        this.title = title;
        this.content = content;
        this.image = image;
        this.type = type;
        this.archived = archived;
        this.check = check;
        this.protect = protect;
        this.password = password;
    }

    // ---- setter
    public void setId(int id){
           this.id = id;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title){
           this.title = title;
    }

    public void setContent(String content){
        this.content = content;
    }

    public void setImage(String image){
        this.image = image;
    }

    public void setType(String type){
        this.type = type;
    }

    public void setArchived(int archived){
        this.archived = archived;
    }

    public void setCheck(int check){
        this.check = check;
    }

    public void setProtect(int protect){
        this.protect = protect;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password){
        this.password = password;
    }

    public void setDate_added(String date_added){
        this.date_added = date_added;
    }

    // --- getter ---

    public int getId(){
           return id;
    }

    public String getTitle(){
           return title;
    }

    public String getContent(){
        return content;
    }

    public String getImage(){
        return image;
    }

    public String getType(){
        return type;
    }

    public int getArchived(){
        return archived;
    }

    public int getCheck(){
        return check;
    }

    public int getProtect(){
        return protect;
    }

    public String getPassword(){
        return password;
    }

    public String getDate_added() {
        return date_added;
    }

    public String toString(){
           return "Book  >> id:"+id+" | title:"+title+" | author:";
    }
}
```

and this is method for showing the data in list view but BookTable is class of connect and get data from sqlite

```
public void list_Books() {

        BookTable bt = new BookTable(getActivity());
        adapter = new CustomListViewAdapter(getActivity(), bt.getAllBooks());

        list.setAdapter(adapter);

        list.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {

            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View arg1,int pos, long id) {
                  selected = adapter.getBookId(pos);
                  row_type = (TextView) arg1.findViewById(R.id.row_note_type); 
                    return false;
                }
            });
           registerForContextMenu(list);
    }
```

i want to know how can i sorting this data by objects of my Book class

please i want speed answer

Comment: Lists just show the data.  Your SQL query will need to hand the sorted list to the adapter or you can take the data from your SQL query and hand sort it.

Comment: nice put if i want to sort my custom adapter

Comment: first decide by what parameter you want to sort your data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach of sorting is for your object `Book` to implement `Comparable` interface:

```
public class Book implements Comparable<Book>{

    private int id;

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Book another) {
        if(this.id >= another.id)
            return 1;
        return -1;
    }
}
```

If you want to sort after you query the data from database you can just call the `Collections` `sort()` method:

```
Collections.sort(list);
```

If you dont want to implement `Comparable` interface, you can just create a `Comparator` and call the following method of `Collections`:

```
Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Book>() {

    @Override
    public int compare(Book lhs, Book rhs) {
        if(lhs.id >= rhs.id)
            return 1;
        return -1;
    }
});
```

To reverse the order (as frequently it is requiredfor sorting):

```
Collections.sort(list, Collections.reverseOrder());
```

After you sort the list dont forget to notify the adapter to refresh the view:

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```